# Cursor problems

Tags: lubuntu, mouse, touchpad

I am running Lubuntu Bionic Beaver 18.04 on an old Toshiba laptop. It has been running well, but now I have a problem with the mouse cursor, it slides off the screen and hides, if I leave the cursor in the middle of the screen on the desktop,it will slowly slide down to the left hand corner of the screen and hide, I can eventually retrieve it, but I can't figure out why it is doing it, I am using the notebook touchpad. Help please!

Comment: Personally I'd boot a 'live' system (whatever you like, I'd suggest something very different to your Lubuntu 18.04 LTS) and see if the issue occurs there too...  If it does, it's something *strange* with your mouse/device, and not a configuration option (the mouse on this desktop does strange things, but it's not the OS but the mouse as it misbehaves on any *live* system booted). If it only occurs on your Lubuntu, then it's likely a configuration setting or device recognition issue, but I'd check hardware first (*Warning: my own mouse issues very strongly influence my thinking*)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the advice, I am a bit of a novice to the Ubuntu way, what exactly is "Booting to a live system" sorry I don't understand.

Comment: A 'live' system is where you boot your Ubuntu/Lubuntu install media (not the Lubuntu *alternate* media though as it's not *live*) and select the "Try" or "Start" option. It creates a temporary "/" (called root) in memory and operates completely from memory. It's intended to let you *try* the system before you decide to install it (get a *feel* for how it performs, what of your hardware is recognizes etc), but is also really useful in troubleshooting, diagnosing issues, and actually fixing issues (including on install windows). Something very different so it's using a different kernel etc

Comment: An example of something different maybe openSUSE (I'm using as example only; I'm not sure it actually has 'live' media though I know it's available even if via re-spin). Debian maybe easier though (it's closer to Ubuntu though which is why I mentioned opensuse), and Debian still have x86/32-bit ISOs if your box is that old (2004-2008 era x86 only were common).  If you have your Lubuntu media handy (and it's not an *alternate*, and have 1GB ram or more) use that first. If it has the same issue, then I'd go for something different (debian, better test is further away like opensuse/fedora/etc)

Comment: Thanks, I thought I had found a fix too the problem with sudo apt install libinput-tools, it seemed to work for a while, but now the cursor has gone nuts again!